# FME : Value of attribute could not be converted to type 'date'

Tags: fme-form

I am unable to integrate new data into a PostGIS table with FME, I get this error message. Yet, the original data in the Shapefile is already in date type. Some of the values are just 00000000 (when date is unknown), while others are YYYYMMDD.

> Value of attribute 'xxx' could not be converted to type 'date'.
> Feature will be logged and skipped
>
> Attribute(encoded: UTF-8)   : xxx has value `00000000'
>
> Attribute(encoded: UTF-8)   : xxx has value '19880101'

Comment: do a tester with 00000000 and replace with a real date (can be 19000101)

Comment: it's ok I found out, in fact PostGIS fordbis attribute values ​​'00000000' of type date, I replaced with '99991231' and it works

Comment: @Eliasse, feel free to answer your own question. It ensures that others with this question can scroll past the comments and find the answer easily.